# Error when put multiply formula into the cells in the table Excel

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

I am working on a Excel Add-in project now. I tried to put my formulas into a bunch of cells in the Excel. It works well when these cells do not include in the table of the worksheet. But after I formed a table at first, I tried to assign these formula that store in a 2D array to the Range. It raised a bug that the cells in each column have same formula as the first one cell in this column. But in fact, the formulas in the array are not different.
So I suppose there has some different when people want to assign the formula to cells that in or not in a table. But I can not find reference about it. The way that I do to avoid this situation now is that I try to assign the formula to cells before form a table. But I really have confusion about this bug.

Comment: I try to assign the formulas to the cells once. I can set the formula to the cell one by one. But it is really slow.It is not an efficient way to do.

Comment: For instance, I want to assign the formula to Range[B2:D4], like "=A2" is for cell B2, "=A3" is for cell B3,  "=A4" is for cell B4 and so on. But after I formed a table for this range, I assign the array to this range,  the formulas of B2,B3,B4 all are "=A2".  I did check my array that is correct,so I suppose that it just has some problem in setting the formula of range.

Comment: I knew what you mean. But I did set appplication.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I want to continue to use my previous method, I need to add appplication.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = false into loop. It is what I do not want. So I switch to another method that using one feature of table.For one cell, I want to give it a formula that includes other cells in the same line with this range to calculate something, it would be better if I use Table[[#This Row],[ColumnName]].